# Facebook fonts look weird on firefox in 12.04

Tags: firefox, fonts, facebook

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on this machine and noticed the fonts on facebook.com look very different from how they used to look on 10.04 or Windows. They seem to be smaller and "washed out" (hard to describe).

I haven't noticed this problem on other websites

Any idea what could cause this problem and how to fix it? I am using the Firefox and always have for many years on different machines.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible explanations for this—

1— You haven't installed the ms-core-fonts package, and you're seeing the backup ubuntu fonts. You can install it with `sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts`. You can also search for it in the software center.

2— You are seeing the Ubuntu Anti-aliasing. Unlike Windows AA, it anti-aliases in two dimensions, while in Windows, Cleartype does RGBa anti-aliasing, but only in the horizontal dimension. (Which looks better at small sizes, but causes noticeable jaggedness at large font sizes).

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/81/Textsamples.PNG))</sub>

You can get the best of both worlds(RGBa in the horizontal and regular AA in the vertical) by adjusting the Font Antialiasing settings—There are several tools for this, one of which is the Advanced settings tool [Install `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`].

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was caused by experiences installing very light fonts.

Solution: run font-manager (must be as ROOT) and disable the User fonts that caused the problem you saw in facebook.